# In Node.js, is setTimeout reliable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to perform many "setTimeouts" 60 seconds.  Basically, I'm creating a database record, and 60 seconds from now, I need to check whether the database record was changed.

I don't want to implement a "job queue" since it's such a simple thing, and I definitely need to check it around the 60 second mark.

Is it reliable, or will it cause issues?

Comment: anecdotally: yes, officially: no, it depends on workload. if you just need it to within 1000ms, you're probably fine, but if people will die because it's 1500ms off, use something better.

Comment: define "on the dot". Are you worried that the timer will be triggered at a wrong time? Or that it could be "lost" altogether? Your callback will be called after at least 60 seconds, but it may be slightly later. In particular, it won't interrupt other work.

Comment: I just need to be triggered around 60 seconds. Doesn't need to be anything important or on the dot. People won't die :). It can be a few seconds off.

Comment: then yeah, if your box normally doesn't run under huge loads, then you will be fine; node's pretty good about it compared to a browser where all sorts of stuff can delay the thread...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` the only guarantee that you get is that the code will not be executed **before** the programmed time.

It can however start somewhat later because other code that is being executed when the clock ticks (in other words other code will not be interrupted in the middle of the handling of an event to process a timeout or interval event).

If you don't have long blocking processing in your code it means that timed events will be reasonably accurate. If you are instead using long blocking calls then probably node is not the correct tool (it's designed around the idea of avoiding blocking "synch" calls).

Answer (score 1):

you should try WorkerTimer.js it is more good for handling background processes and more accurate than the traditional setInterval or Timeout.

it is available as a node.js npm package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-timer

Comment: Albeit interesting, WorkerTimer solves a different problem: timers in browser are late when the window is unfocused. The question is about node.js